# How to find biggest folders (by number of files) in Windows

Tags: windows-7

My Windows 7 search is pretty slow on one computer and fast on the other.  I figured out that one computer has 90,000 files indexed while the other has 1.5 million.

So I'd like to find the biggest folders by number of files, since some are bound to be irrelevant, and exclude them.

I have tools for finding the biggest folders by data size, but not by number of files within.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you were using Windows XP, you could use the [Folder Size](http://foldersize.sourceforge.net/) shell-extension which gives you a few columns that you can add to Explorer to show the size of a folder, as well as the number files/folders/both contained therein, thus allowing you to view and sort them right inside Explorer.

Unfortunately, Vista and higher have dropped the API functionality that Folder Size and similar programs use, so they no longer work.

Instead, you’ll have to use a non-shell-extension. Fortunately there are several programs that can do a pretty good job of visualizing space usage on a file-system.

Most of them have a few different modes including text-list/tree (like in Explorer), [pie-graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pie_graph), and [treemap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping), in which the files and sub-directories are represented by squares or rectangles. There should be an option to display the number of files/folders in addition to the size, usually in text-list/tree mode. Sometimes, to get the number of files/folders, you need to select the folder and view its properties (which is less convenient, but still easier than manually in Explorer).

Here are some of the most popular ones (some freeware, others shareware):

- [SequoiaView](http://www.win.tue.nl/sequoiaview)
- [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/)
- [Space](http://www.andyhsoftware.co.uk/space)
- [FolderSize](http://foldersize.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Yup, WinDirStat is the quickest and easiest because the default view has the number of items right there in the list.

Comment: WinDirStat is my favorite too.

Answer (score 6):

And another, [TreeSize Free](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/).
     (In this shot, the directories are named 0-F.)

[image]

Answer (score 6):

One quick way to get a sorted list of folders by number of files - including subfolders - is:

## PowerShell 3+

```
$a=@{}
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath 'D:\' -Recurse -Directory -ErrorAction Ignore | Foreach {
    $a[$_.Fullname] = (Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $_.Fullname -Recurse -File -ErrorAction Ignore).Count
} 
$a.GetEnumerator() | Sort Value -Descending | Format-List
```

## Example output

[image]

#### For those who are interested in how it works

- `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath 'D:\' -Recurse -Directory` loops through all subfolders of a given directory. Change the path to your needs. ([`-LiteralPath` avoids errors from `[` and `]` brackets.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21614316/879))
- In each subfolder use `(Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $_.Fullname -Recurse -File).Count` to count the number of files including files in subfolders. Folders itself don't count. Only files do.
- For each subfolder, add a new hash table entry `$a[$_.Fullname] = myValue` with the current directory as name. As value add our previously mentioned files count
- After all the work is done, use `$a.GetEnumerator()` to break the hash table back into multiple items and pipe them to a `Sort-Object` command which sorts the hash table by value and ascending

Comment:  This executed much faster than I was expecting.

Answer (score 2):

I use a program called [windirstat](http://windirstat.info/) which scans through all the files and folders on a drive and gives a nice graphical display of which files or folders are using the most space. You can then move or delete unwanted files and tidy up your disk.

Answer (score 1):

Start with Dust [4e1180e5](//github.com/bootandy/dust/commit/4e1180e5) (2020-08-30), you can now do this like so:

```
-f, --filecount
Directory 'size' is number of child files/dirs not disk size
```

Example output:

```
PS C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Local> dust -f
577            ┌── Default
628          ┌─┴ User Data
629        ┌─┴ Edge
1,154    ┌─┴ Microsoft
1,901    ├── Packages
407      │     ┌── 41ad6w4a.default-release-4
493      │     │   ┌── entries
497      │     │ ┌─┴ cache2
573      │     ├─┴ 7eccqsn1.default-release-1-1597857941226
3,952    │   ┌─┴ Profiles
3,953    │ ┌─┴ Firefox
3,954    ├─┴ Mozilla
3,096    │       ┌── entries
3,100    │     ┌─┴ cache2
3,269    │   ┌─┴ 56uzf1ra.Sunday
10,341   │   │   ┌── entries
10,344   │   │ ┌─┴ cache2
10,428   │   ├─┴ 7nx7hnxa.68-edition-default
13,698   │ ┌─┴ Profiles
13,699   ├─┴ Waterfox
21,181 ┌─┴ .
```

Since this was just released, I had to build it myself with this command:

```
$env:RUSTFLAGS = '-C link-arg=-s'
cargo build --release
```

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell script which accepts wildcard directory path and wildcard filenames to display a table of file frequencies sorted by most-to-least. Credit to @nixda for providing a starting point.

```
$SearchPath='E:\myfolder1\*\myfolder2\'
$FileMatch='*.json'
$a=@{}
 Get-ChildItem $SearchPath -Directory | Foreach {
    $a[$_.Fullname] = (Get-ChildItem $_.Fullname -Recurse -Include $FileMatch).Count
} 
$a.GetEnumerator() | Sort Value -Descending | Format-Table -AutoSize
```